# TSql SqlParameters - Illegal Value or Collation issue?

Tags: t-sql, ascii, collation

The following sql runs and return a row

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol='01««01'
```

However if this sql is parameterised and executed

```
EXEC execustesql 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol=@p1',N'p1 nvarchar(6)',@p1=N'01««01'
```

It returns 0 rows.

I have tried explicitly adding various COLLATIONs (Latin1_General_CI_AI, SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) to the filter to both the column and the parameter placeholder e.g.

```
WHERE MyCol COLLATE collation=@p1 COLLATE collation
```

But can't seem to get any rows returned.

A further complication, which I'm not sure is relevant, is that the character « is ascii 174, but if I run

```
SELECT convert(varbinary(max),'01««01')
returns 0x3031ABAB3031  i.e. 171
```

so I've also tried playing around with the value and replacing ascii 174 with asc 171 even though it is a different char.

So is my problem a collation issue or do Sql Parameters not accept values which contain certain ascii values ... or something else?

Comment: just to note that there's no such thing as 'ascii 174' or indeed 171: ASCII only goes to 127, beyond that you have to be careful

Comment: Tip: A string literal for an `NVarChar()` value ought to be prefixed with `N`, e.g. `@p1 = N'01««01'`. Ref. [Unicode strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#unicode-strings).

Comment: Sorry ... my bad ... it actually does and I've copied it incorrectly.. I'll update the above .tvm